# How to input to stdin when tee is used

Tags: bash, tee

I typically use tee to save program out to some other file, e.g.

```
python -c "print('haha');" | tee -a /tmp/tmp.txt
```

However, this can't work when the program need to read from stdin

```
python -c "print('haha');import pdb; pdb.set_trace()" | tee -a /tmp/tmp.txt
```

Program will hang there without printing anything. How to deal with this? Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
python -c "print('haha');import pdb, sys; pdb.Pdb(stdout=sys.stderr).set_trace()" | tee -a /tmp/tmp.txt
```

Or, if you are on Linux:

```
stdbuf -o0 python -c "print('haha');import pdb, sys; pdb.set_trace()" | tee -a /tmp/tmp.txt
```

In the first case above, the `pdb` is directed to send its output to stderr.  This means that it does not go to `tee` and instead goes directly to the terminal.

In the second case, the `stdbuf` utility is used to turn off output buffering. `stdbuf` is part of GNU coreutils.

#### Improved version

While the above code runs, pdb behaves differently when its  stdout  is  not  a  tty.  In particular, it does not support all of pdb's interactive command-line features, such as control keys.  As pointed out by blueyed, the [`script` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61833/1920) is able to overcome this so that the program runs as if its stdout was not re-directed:

```
script -q -c 'python -c "import pdb, sys; pdb.set_trace()"' /dev/null | tee -a /tmp/tmp.txt
```

Comment: Any idea why the cursor keys do not work in this mode?  The input gets displayed as `^[[A` verbatim.  That applies also to `Ctrl-A`, being displayed as `^A`.  Happens with `python -c 'import pdb; pdb.set_trace()' | tee /tmp/tmp.txt` already.

Comment: @blueyed I see the same behavior.  At them moment, I have no work-around.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61833/1920 works for me: `script -q -c 'python -c "import pdb, sys; pdb.set_trace()"' /dev/null | tee -a /tmp/tmp.txt` on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I am no python expert, but you need to flush your output from the program that is piped, otherwise you 'haha' gets stuck in the output buffer.